# How to add remote repositories on xCode service on OSX 3.2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

I'm referring the apple's documentation herehttps://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1.

The 'Connect to Remote Repositories' options is not been displayed.

Comment: There is no such thing as OS X 3.2.1. What do you actually mean?

Comment: I think @Kamlesh Hatariya refers to the version of the server app

Comment: I want to use repositories hosted on remote server (like github or bitbucket) on Xcode service. The documentation mentioned in the original question shows that its possible to add. But there is no option for it on osx 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, previous versions of OS X Server required you to add remote repositories, whereas v3.2.1 just uses the ones set up in Xcode itself. In [what seems to be the most up-to-date version of the Continuous Integration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1), the "To add a remote repository to the Xcode service" section has been removed completely, and the "Configure the Xcode service to connect to your remote repositories" line has been moved above the instructions for adding repositories to Xcode, all of which seem to support that.

Having said that, I currently can't get mine to work so I'm waiting on Apple Support to get back to me, but I think that's the theory!

Comment: I figured out, The remote repository will be added when you create a bot. You don't have to add repository in OSX server.